# How to have different elements in collection view?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

so I try to have collection view but been thinking is it possible to have different element in each cell view? For Example: in the first cell I have the whole cell covered by `UIImageView` while some specific cells only got `UITextView`.

Here's an example that I'm talking about, Medium iOS App.

[image]

Comment: Please search for your question before you ask it, this has been asked many many times: https://www.google.se/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=uicollectionview+with+different+cells+swift&*

Answer (score 0):

Create several prototype cells, each formatted with whichever UI elements you want, and dequeue the appropriate cell for each different type of data you want to display.

Comment: Downvoted because this should be flagged as a duplicate since it is a very basic question to the UICollectionView element.